# Loading null data while fetching data from service using DataServiceQuery

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I tried to load the data using entities and checked the connection using HTTPClient.

The data  queried using DataServiceQuery and here the code example i have used

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Members

```
    NorthwindEntities northwindEntity;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private List<Order> gridSource;
    public List<Order> GridSource
    {
        get { return gridSource; }
        set { gridSource = value; RaisePropertyChanged("GridSource"); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Ctor

    public ViewModel()
    {
        gridSource = new List<Order>();
        try
        {
            LoadData();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    async void LoadData()
    {
        string uri = "http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/";
        var re = await CheckConnection(uri);
        if (re.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {

            northwindEntity = new NorthwindEntities(new Uri(uri));
            DataServiceQuery query1 = (DataServiceQuery)northwindEntity.Orders;
            //query1.BeginExecute();
            DataServiceQuery<Order> query = northwindEntity.Orders.Expand("Customer");
            query = query.Skip<Order>(1).Take<Order>(50) as DataServiceQuery<Order>;
            IAsyncResult ar = query.BeginExecute(null, null);
            var items = query.EndExecute(ar);
            gridSource = items.ToList() as List<Order>;

        }
    }


    private async Task<HttpWebResponse> CheckConnection(String URL)
    {

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)await req.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return response;

    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Member

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I am unable to get the results after querying the data . Please refer the below screen shot[image]

Checked while executing query and the number records in table wont displayed and control loaded empty .

Please suggest how to fetch the data from entities in Xamarin forms .